# Port Static PHP Website to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to port a static site done in PHP to Google App Engine using webapp2 & jinja2.
My PHP's index.php looks like this :

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header"><?php require_once DIR_HTML."header.phtml" ?></header>
    <section id="main"><?php require_once DIR_HTML.$_GET['page'].".phtml" ?></section>
    <footer id="footer"><?php require_once DIR_HTML."footer.phtml" ?></footer>
</div>
</body>
```

And in my google-app-engine code I have this :

```
import webapp2, jinja2, os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class AboutPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/about.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))        

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/about', AboutPage)], debug=True)
```

How do I replicate the same kind of functionality in Python ?

Answer (score 2):

[Template Inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/)

> The most powerful part of Jinja is template inheritance. Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
            &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Once I discovered the line statements in Jinja2 (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#line-statements) I stopped using the traditional way.. The code is so much cleaner.. here is an example of a base.html using line statements http://goo.gl/KRifu

Comment: v.interesting! Thanks for the heads up.